# Server error 500 upon Wordpress WP-Admin Login

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting

I migrated our website from our local pc to our server in GoDaddy.

```
http://qdf-phils.com/
```

Everything works fine except that I cannot login in the admin page. I cann access the login page which is

```
http://qdf-phils.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fqdf-phils.com%2Fwp-admin%2F&reauth=1
```

Then I type the username and password and after clicking login I get

```
Server error 500
```

This is **NOT** `Internal Server Error 500`

Here's the screenshot

[image]

I believe I configure everything correctly.

My htaccess

```
# BEGIN WordPress
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
    </IfModule>

    # END WordPress

    # BEGIN Hotlinking
    <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^$
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://qdf-phils.com/.*$ [NC]
    RewriteRule \.(pdf|doc|docx|odt|rtf|txt)$ [R=302,L]
    </IfModule>

    # END Hotlinking
    # BEGIN Force Download
    AddType application/octet-stream .pdf .txt

    # END Force Download
```

I also changed the values in the database table `wp_options`

```
siteurl and home
```

is has proper values. Is there anything I missed? I am uploading it in a shared unlimited hosting togther with other laravel based projects. I'm thinking that is it affected by other Laravel's .htaccess?

Comment: Not that this is an issue for sure, but I usually use https://github.com/interconnectit/Search-Replace-DB to replace DB values when moving from local to production or vice-versa. Perhaps you can give it a try if it solves the issue. Also check that you don't have some globals forced inside wp-config.php

Comment: 500 error is a server error, have you tried contacting GoDaddy to check it out? Maybe it is a problem on their side